# Regex Track1 Magnetic Stripe

Tags: regex, regex-group, magnetic-cards

How can I create regex rule for name in Track1, following these rules:

- Allowed Characters would be:  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789
  .()-$
- Not Allowed Characters would be: ^!"&'*+,:;<=>@_[]#%?
- Required character - only must character **/** appear
- The max size is 26 characters , min size 2.

I tried:

```
\^[^\^!"&'*+,:;<=>@_\[\]\\#%?]{2,26}\^ Result FAIL: removing "/" will pass pattern 
\^([-.()0-9a-zA-Z]*\/[-.()\w\s\/]*){1,26}\^ Result FAIL: more than 26 characters will pass pattern
^[-.()\w\s\/]{2,26}\^ Result FAIL: removing "/" will pass pattern
```

Sample of Name in Track1:

- ^`TEST/TEST`^- Should Pass
- ^`TEST TEST`^- Should Fail
- ^`TEST/TE/ST`^ - Should Fail
- ^`TEST/TE+ST`^ - Should Fail

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to do this with a regular expression? Validating the total length of the field would be challenging while also ensuring presence of a single character. Much simpler to do with a programming language of some sort.

Comment: I can do that of course. I thought it would be better to create one regex rule handling it.

Comment: Well, come back to your 1000 character regex in a year and see if it makes sense to you. Shorter != better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there has to be at least `^` at the start and end, and there has to be at least a single `/` then the minimum amount of characters would be 3 instead of 2.

In that case, you might use:

```
\^(?=[A-Z .()\/-]{1,24}\^)[A-Z .()-]*\/[A-Z .()-]*\^
```

**Explanation**

- `\^` Match `^`
- `(?=[A-Z .()\/-]{1,24}\^)` Positive lookahead, assert 1,24 of the allowed chars followed by `^` to the right to make a total of 2-26 characters
- `[A-Z .()-]*\/[A-Z .()-]*` Match `/` between optional allowed chars
- `\^` Match `^`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ARfUaI/1).

If the `/` can not be at the start or at the end (matching at least 5 characters in that case)

```
\^(?=[A-Z .()\/-]{1,24}\^)[A-Z .()-]+\/[A-Z .()-]+\^
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nDCOhi/1)